# How to convert a ps vector of 4 float to 4 doubles and store to a pd array?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, simd, sse2

Is it possible with `SSE2`/`SIMD` to store `__m128` values (4 `float`) to an array of `double`?

I need to switch from this code:

```
double *pC = c[voiceIndex];
__m128d v_result;

_mm_store_pd(pC, v_result);
```

to this:

```
double *pC = c[voiceIndex];
__m128 v_result_float;

_mm_store_ps(pC, v_result_float);
```

Except instead of doing a 128-bit store of 4x 32-bit `float`s, I need to convert them to `double`.

I can't change the "source" `pC` array (which is `double`)

Comment: Do you want to convert the 4 floats into 4 doubles or just store 2 floats into each place of a double?

Comment: @chtz convert the 4 floats into 4 doubles, I believe (not sure about what you are meaning with the second case). So if I have 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f and 0.4f stored into v_result_float, I will store 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and 0.4 respectively into pC[0], pC[1], pC[2] and pC[3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, this is the inverse question to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517648/how-to-convert-two-pd-into-one-ps). In this case you need to `movhlps` (`_mm_movelh_ps`) the high words into the low words before converting the second half:

```
void foo(double* dest, __m128 input) 
{
    // assuming dest is nicely aligned
    _mm_store_pd(dest,   _mm_cvtps_pd(input));
    _mm_store_pd(dest+2, _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_movehl_ps(input, input)));
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks! This seems to add a bit of overhead (2 stores instead of 1) instead of simply "store at once". I'll investigate...

Comment: I don't see another way of converting the high-words of a `__m128` register. In some cases it may make sense to do all operations in the `double` domain, instead of converting to `float` and back (assuming that is where the `float` vector originated from). But that is a thing you should benchmark (with actual data).

Comment: I actually need to do it because I process an approx functions (exp) which its accurated and faster with float, not doubles

Comment: Converting 4 floats at once would be possible with AVX: [`_mm256_cvtps_pd`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX&expand=1744&text=cvtps_pd)

Comment: I'm with SSE2 only ;)